# Why am I getting an error in CakePHP that my view is not found?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using cakephp for form designing application.

In my code

```
<?php echo $html->link('Delete', array('action' => 'deleteForm', 'id' => $r['Form']['id']), null, 'Are you sure?' )?>
```

In my controller

```
   function deleteForm($id = null) {
          $this->Form->del($id);
          $this->Session->setFlash('Your entry has been deleted.');
          $this->redirect(array('action'=>'homepage'));
   }
```

In my deleteForm.ctp file I kept a back link only.

The Form is deleted and the Flash message came. But showing an error of

```
forms/deleteForm/1 is not found in this SERVER.
```

**Solution:**
     The error is because I have saved the view file as deleteForm.ctp instead of delete_form.ctp. Now it works.

Answer (score 4):

This is your second very basic question about PHP and CakePHP, might I suggest you to read the respective documentation?

- [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/)
- [CakePHP Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/)

And just to point you in the right direction, here is the documentation for AppController::redirect():

- [3.5.4.2.1   Redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/view/57/Controller-Methods#redirect-425)

Please read the documentation before posting simple questions which would be answered by a quick peek.

Comment: This code i did is from the Site That you gave only..
I have done with the sample posts ..Now only i m getting the errors

Answer (score -1):

I have the same question before, I used WAMP, and the controller's encoding is UTF-8, in this case, redirect method doesn't work, but change the file's encoding to ANSI, it works!

So, try to change the encoding to ANSI in windows.